# Expose kernel for existing environment on Vertex AI User Managed Notebook startup

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

This is a continuation of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73649262/create-custom-kernel-via-post-startup-script-in-vertex-ai-user-managed-notebook), posted here because it was too complicated for a comment.

**TL;DR**

In a Vertex AI User Managed Notebook, how does one retain the exposed kernel icons for existing venv (and conda, if possible) environments stored on the data disk, through repeated stop and start cycles?

**Details**

I am using User Managed Notebook Instances built off a Docker image. Once the Notebook is launched, I manually go in create a custom environment. For the moment, let's say this is a venv python environment. The environment works fine and I can expose the kernel so it shows as an icon in the Jupyter Lab's Launcher. If I shut the instance down and restart it, the icon is gone. I have been trying to create a start-up script that re-exposes the kernel, but it is not working properly. I have been trying to use method #2 proposed by @gogasca in the link above. Among other operations (which do execute correctly), my start-up script contains the following:

```
cat << 'EOF' > /home/jupyter/logs/exposeKernel.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -x
if [ -d /home/jupyter/envs ]; then
  # For each env creation file...
  for i in /home/jupyter/envs/*.sh; do
      tempName="${i##*/}"
      envName=${tempName%.*}
      # If there is a corresponding env directory, then expose the kernel
      if [ -d /home/jupyter/envs/${envName} ]; then
        /home/jupyter/envs/${envName}/bin/python3 -m ipykernel install --prefix=/root/.local --name $envName &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
        echo -en "Kernel created for: $envName \n" &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
      else
        echo -en "No kernels can be exposed\n" &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
      fi
  done
fi
EOF
chown root /home/jupyter/logs/exposeKernel.sh
chmod a+r+w+x /home/jupyter/logs/exposeKernel.sh
su -c '/home/jupyter/logs/exposeKernel.sh' root
echo -en "Existing environment kernels have been exposed\n\n" &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
```

I am attempting to log the operations, and I see in the log that the kernel is created successfully in the same location that it would be created if I were to manually activate the environment and expose the kernel from within. Despite the apparent success in the log (no errors, at least), the kernel icon does not appear. If I manually run the exposeKernel.sh script from the terminal using `su -c '/home/jupyter/logs/exposeKernel.sh' root`, it also works fine and the kernel *is* exposed correctly. @gogasca's comments on the aforementioned thread suggest that I should be using the jupyter user instead of root, but repeated testing and logging indicates that the jupyter user fails to execute the code while root succeeds (though neither create the kernel icon when called from the start-up script).

**Questions:**

(1) My goal is to automatically re-expose the existing environment kernels on startup. Presumably they disappear each time the VM is stopped and started because there is some kind of linking to the boot disk that is rebuilt each time. What is the appropriate strategy here? Is there a way to build the environments (interested in both conda and venv) so that their kernel icons don't vaporize on shut-down?

(2) If the answer to (1) is no, then why does the EOF-created file fail to accomplish the job when called from a start-up script?

(3) Tangentially related, am I correct in thinking that the [post-startup-script](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/notebooks/instances/create#--post-startup-script) executes only once during the initial Notebook instance creation process, while the the [startup-script or startup-script-url](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux) executes each time the Notebook is started?